# FilenotFound exception while loading from a .properties file in Mule 3.8

Tags: deployment, dependency-properties, mule-studio, filenotfoundexception, anypoint-studio

I have imported a project from a Git repository.When I try to deploy to ESB, the deployment fails and reports it cannot find the properties file.
//org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [config.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBean
Factory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:89) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors
    (PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors
    (PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:162) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]

I am using a properties file for multiple environment details and based on the environment name I am picking up the file and copying under src/main/resources folder . However even though I am able to see that the files is being properly picked up and copied to the location src/main/resources.
Others seem to have been able to  deploy it successfully. I tried moving the properties files to the src/main/resources folder with the same result. 
Why isn't the ESB able to find the properties files located in /src/main/resources?

Here's the code snippet:

Answer (score 0):

keep your config.properties file in your classpath and refer it as below

```
<context:property-placeholder location="config.properties" />
```